# I want to retain a selected value from a spinner dropdown and identify it with a key value from enum

Tags: android, enums, android-spinner

So, I have a class for enum, like this:

```
public class EnumActivities {
public enum ActivitiesModeEnum {
    ACTIVITY_0(0,"NONE"),
    ACTIVITY_1(1, "AEROBICS"),
    ACTIVITY_2(2, "CYCLING"),
    ACTIVITY_3(3, "RUNNING"),
    ACTIVITY_4(4, "STRENGTH"),
    ACTIVITY_5(5, "WALKING");

    private final String activityName;
    private int activityNumber;


    private ActivitiesModeEnum(final int activityNumber, final String activityName) {
        this.activityNumber = activityNumber;
        this.activityName = activityName;
    }

    public String getActivityName() {
        return activityName;
    }

    public int getActivityNumber() {
        return activityNumber;
    }

    public static ActivitiesModeEnum valueOfActivity(final int activityNumber) {

        final ActivitiesModeEnum[] values = ActivitiesModeEnum.values();
        for (final ActivitiesModeEnum activityModeEnum : values) {
            if (activityModeEnum.getActivityNumber() == activityNumber)
                return activityModeEnum;
        }
        return ACTIVITY_0;
    }

    public static List<ActivitiesModeEnum> getAll() {
        final List<ActivitiesModeEnum> valuesList = new ArrayList<ActivitiesModeEnum>();
        final ActivitiesModeEnum[] values = ActivitiesModeEnum.values();
        for (final ActivitiesModeEnum activityModeEnum : values) {
            valuesList.add(activityModeEnum);
        }
        return valuesList;
    }

}
```

and I want to retain the selected item from my spinner in a variable called, activityType, in function of my enum, could someone please give me some clues how could i do it?

Comment: Are your spinners initialized with the output of `getAll()`?

Comment: No, I have only set a listener for a selected item

Comment: How do you initialize your spinners?

Comment: It is only one spinner: final Spinner spinnerOfActivities = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_activities);
        spinnerOfActivities.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,activities));

Comment: In order to make a connection between the selected item of the Spinner and your enum you need to mention what data you use for the adapter. What type is activities in your code?

Comment: Here is my java class where I use the spinner: http://paste.org/73894

Comment: In the OnItemSelectedListener: `String selectedActivity = ((ArrayAdapter<String>)adapterView.getAdapter()).getItem
                (position);
        int activityType = 0;
        for (ActivitiesModeEnum act : ActivitiesModeEnumt.values()) {
            if (act.getActivityName().equals(selectedActivity.toUpperCase())) {
                activityType = act.getActivityNumber();
                break;
            }
        };`

Comment: Keep in mind that your implementation is very fragile, also if you're going to write an enum but still use int identifiers you might as well implement a basic class to wrap your data.